# How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I plot the following:

```
library(ggplot2)    

carrots <- data.frame(length = rnorm(500000, 10000, 10000))
cukes <- data.frame(length = rnorm(50000, 10000, 20000))
carrots$veg <- 'carrot'
cukes$veg <- 'cuke'
vegLengths <- rbind(carrots, cukes)

ggplot(vegLengths, aes(length, fill = veg)) +
 geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
```

Now say, I only want to plot the region between `x=-5000` to `5000`, instead of the entire range.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 709, accepted):

Basically you have two options

```
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5000, 5000))
```

or

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5000, 5000))
```

Where the first removes all data points outside the given range and the second only adjusts the visible area. In most cases you would not see the difference, but if you fit anything to the data it would probably change the fitted values.

You can also use the shorthand function `xlim` (or `ylim`), which like the first option removes data points outside of the given range:

```
+ xlim(-5000, 5000)
```

For more information check the description of [**`coord_cartesian`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_cartesian.html).

The [RStudio cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) for `ggplot2` makes this quite clear visually. Here is a small section of that cheatsheet:

[image]

*Distributed under [CC BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)*.

Comment: there's also now `library(scales); ... + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5000, 5000), oob=squish)` (the default is `oob=censor`); see `?squish`, `?censor`: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/AsJ6xpmR9tU

Comment: NB. this might be problematic if you're dealing with lines/polygons where some vertices are outside the limits, as the whole object is removed from the plot

Comment: @geotheory: is that also true of the `coord_cartesian` approach?

Comment: No I should've been more specific, just the first method

Comment: In practice, for 'printing' purposes, with ``coord_cartesian(xlim = `` you probably need to reset ``ylim`` as well, and reset the label and grid breaks.

Comment: Hello, I'm creating a complex plot that uses geom_smooth().
And I don't know why these two approaches produce different curves, though keeping everything else the same:
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.013))
and 
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.013))
Which one is the proper one?
I just want to cut the y-axis.

Answer (score 58):

Quick note: if you're also using `coord_flip()` to flip the x and the y axis, you won't be able to set range limits using `coord_cartesian()` because those two functions are exclusive (see [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/647)).

Fortunately, this is an easy fix; set your limits within `coord_flip()` like so:

```
p + coord_flip(ylim = c(3,5), xlim = c(100, 400))
```

This just alters the visible range (i.e. doesn't remove data points).

Comment: I similar but harder question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531149/how-to-set-just-one-limit-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots on how to limit one SIDE ONLY