# Warning message in overlay of density plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a density plot of two datasets (of different size) by writing:

```
data1 <- data.frame(dens = log2(c(tmm.th[,1],bidrar_mest[,1]))
                  , lines = c(rep("all",61893),rep("loaded",50) ))

ggplot(data1, aes(x = dens, fill = lines)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

I get a nice plot showing that the smaller dataset has higher values but I also get a warning message saying:

```
Warning message: Removed 35492 rows containing non-finite values
(stat_density).
```

Can someone explain why and how to get rid of that?

Comment: Do you have negative numbers in your data before the log transform? That would create non-finite values which are then removed... I think the warning suggests you might not have the best understanding of your data, which may be the biggest issue here?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the understanding of the data is not so good, thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, there are no negative numbers before the log transform, if you have any other suggestions what it might be, I would appreciate your input!

Comment: I get this warning when some data points get dropped because I restrict the X range of the plot using `xlim()`

Answer (score 2):

As @Ant and @alexwhan have already pointed out, the problem could be due to:

- points that are negative or equal to zero. In the second case the log-transform would give as output -Inf, which is then dicarded in the analyisis.
- points that are out of the range that it is possible to prescribe.

Since in your case the limit in the x- or y-axis is not set a priori, I would say that the reason is the fisrt one.

Please, see the following links for further explanations:

- http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=23961 (relative to the first case)
- [How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots) (relative to the second).

I hope this can help.

Comment: Actually, another problem in the visualization can be triggered by the presence of 'NA' in your datasets. <br/> The command na.omit should then work for you.