# Limit X and Y axis ranges in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When doing a conventional plot I could use xlim and ylim to show ranges of what I wanted plotted.

How can I achieve this in ggplot?

EDIT: Example of a dataset I plot:

```
real <- read.table("http://pelinfamily.ca/bio/GDR-18_conc.ld", header=F)
dd <- data.frame(Distance=real[,2]-real[,1], r.2=real[,13])

ggplot(dd, aes(x=Distance, y=r.2)) +
   stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom="ribbon", alpha=.4) + 
   stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom="line")
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you are doing `stat_summary` you might consider..

```
+ coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-10, 10), ylim=c(-10, 10))
```

Which will merely "zoom in" without changing the underlying data.

[ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/coord_cartesian.html)

Answer (score 7):

This post actually answers it pretty well:
[How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)

I found:

```
library(scales); 
... + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5000, 5000)
```

to work.

```
... + xlim(-5000, 5000)
```

Did not work for some reason.