# How to control xlim with geom_rect() in R with facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rectangles, facet-wrap

**Goal**: Plot a rectangle (`geom_rect`) that spans the plotting window.

**Problem**: Can't get ggplot2 to accept xlims.

**Example**:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

#Data frame
df <- data.frame(time=seq(ymd_hm('2016-01-26 08:00'),ymd_hm('2016-01-26 18:00'), length.out = 100), y=rnorm(100), facto=rep(c('a','b'), each=50))

#Call to ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(time, y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~facto)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=ymd_hm('2016-01-26 07:00'), xmax=ymd_hm('2016-01-26 20:00'), ymin=-1, ymax=1), fill='skyblue4', alpha=I(0.3), data=df[1,])
```

In plot below, the rectangle does not span the plotting window (desired outcome).  The wider the rectangle, the wider the window, and the rectangle never reaches the sides.

[image]

Simple answer seems to be setting the xlims ([How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)).

However, using `xlim` doesn't seem to take (arg is ignored), you can't use `coord_cartesian` with facets, and applying the `scale_x_datetime` yields unexpected results:

```
ggplot(df, aes(time, y))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~facto)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=ymd_hm('2016-01-26 07:00'), xmax=ymd_hm('2016-01-26 20:00'), ymin=-1, ymax=1), fill='skyblue4', alpha=I(0.3), data=df[1,])+
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(ymd_hm('2016-01-26 08:00'),ymd_hm('2016-01-26 19:00')))
```

**Note how x-values are no longer accurately represented**
[image]

**Further attempts**:
I've tried freeing the scales in the `facet_wrap` without effect.  Also tried calls to `xlim` as a separate line and xlim within the call to `ggplot`, `geom_point`, and `geom_rect`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -1, ymax = 1,
          fill = 'skyblue4', alpha = I(0.3), data = df[1, ])
```

solves the problem:

[image]