# restricting Y axis displayed values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can someone explain why the code below doesn't cut the Y axis off? I am trying to cut off 0 to 50000 and only display values above that. I tried this based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)

```
data(iris)
iris2<-iris[,1:4]*5000  

ggplot(data=iris2, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Sepal.Length)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(5000, 150000)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Because in bar graphs you compare the length of bars starting at 0. This is an instance where `ggplot2` is deliberately designed to make it difficult to make [a misleading plot](http://cloudfront.mediamatters.org/static/uploader/image/2014/03/31/obamacareenrollment-fncchart.jpg).

Comment: After some experimentation with your example it seems the limits are used but in a loose way. If I limit to 100k it plots up to about 110. Similar with the lower number

Comment: I was amused (and slightly horrified)  at what I saw with `+ylim ( 5000, 150000)+`

Comment: @Gregor, I agree, but I am struggling to show a small difference, In my specific case each value is above 5000 and may vary by a hundred or so. The problem is that you can't see the small change between bars

Comment: Right - it's a good indication that you shouldn't be using a bar plot. Just use a line plot or a scatter plot instead!

Comment: Good point..... always a good idea to pick the right tool for the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
ggplot(data=iris2, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Sepal.Length)) + ylim(c(5000, 150000)) +geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

you only need the ylim, the coord_cartesian is not necessary

Comment: Tried that, but it moved my points up, without changing the Y axis

Comment: That is very weird behaviour from ggplot2, do you have the latest version of ggplot2 and R?