# How to remove blank from geom_line in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

geom_line has big gap in line two sides, how to remove this gap!

[image: geom_line]

R scripts is listed as follow,

```
p <- ggplot(singJanS)+ geom_line(aes(x=sn,y=diff))
p <- p  + geom_hline(yintercept=seq(-0.8,0.8,by=0.4), linetype=2, colour="grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(15,744,by=24), linetype=6, colour="red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(23,744,by=24), linetype=6, colour="blue") +
  ylab(Delta~T~'  ('~degree~C~')')+xlab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,120,240,360,480,600,720))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.8,-0.4,0,0.4,0.8)) +theme_bw()
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `xlim(0, 750)` to your graph?

Comment: Thank you! but it is invaild!

Comment: Can you provide the result of `dput(singJanS)` so that we can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Also, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots

Comment: Try adding `expand = c(0, 0)` to your `scale_x_continuous()` line?

Comment: expand = c(0, 0) is OK! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The solution suggested by @Z.Lin works correctly. 
The two gaps are removed if you add `expand = c(0, 0)` to `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
set.seed(1)
singJanS <- data.frame(sn=1:740, diff=rnorm(740)/3)

p <- ggplot(singJanS)+ geom_line(aes(x=sn,y=diff))
p <- p  + geom_hline(yintercept=seq(-0.8,0.8,by=0.4), linetype=2, colour="grey") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(15,744,by=24), linetype=6, colour="red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(23,744,by=24), linetype=6, colour="blue") +
  ylab(Delta~T~'  ('~degree~C~')')+xlab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,120,240,360,480,600,720),expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.8,-0.4,0,0.4,0.8)) +theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

Comment: It is OK! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your code

```
    + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 750))
```

Comment: Thank you! but It's invaild!