# How to mix aes_() and arithmetic calculation in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nse, aesthetics

I am trying to adjust `x` and `ymax` in the following script in `ggplot2` package in `R` to  adjust plotting coordinates of `errorbar`, however it returns errors.

```
  gplot <- function(prd) {

        ggplot() +
        geom_polygon(data=shp.t,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),
                      fill="white",colour="grey") +
        ## Plot errorbar
        geom_errorbar(data=te10.cent,size=2,colour="red",
                      alpha=.8,width=0,
                      aes_(x=quote(long.cent)-350,ymin=quote(lat.cent),　　　　　　　
                                 ymax=quote(lat.cent)+prd))
        }
gplot("Field Name") # Not number but field name of the data frame
```

(Sorry, I cannot upload the actual data frame that I am using.)

These are the errors that I am facing:

> ```
> Error in quote(lat.cent) + prd * .pt : non-numeric argument to binary Operator
> Error in quote(lat.cent)+prd * .pt : non-numeric argument to binary Operator
> ```

It works in both cases if `-350` and `+prd` are omitted from the script or using 'aes' with actual variable in the data frame.
I tried other scripts; `"long.cent"-350` and `"lat.cent"+prd` instead of the above script, however it also returns the same error.

I searched for solutions but all of them explains how to use `aes_` without mixing argument and arithmetic calculation. I need to mix non-standard expression with arithmetic calculation to adjust my plot but how?

Comment: Have you tried using `scale_x_continuous` / `scale_y_continuous` or `coord_cartesian`?  See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example e.g. on one of the build in datasets such as cars or iris?

Comment: Thank you for both of your suggestions, it worked out thanks to @missuse 's solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trust this will resolve your issue:

```
gplot <- function(prd) {

  ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = shp.t,
                 aes_(x = ~long,
                      y = ~lat,
                      group = ~group),
                 fill = "white",
                 colour = "grey") +
    ## Plot errorbar
    geom_errorbar(data = te10.cent,
                  size = 2,
                  colour = "red",
                  alpha = .8,
                  width = 0,
                  aes_(x = ~long.cent - 350,
                       ymin = ~lat.cent,　　　　　　　
                       ymax = ~lat.cent + prd))
}
```

reproducible example:

some data:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_all(~mean(.)) -> summed_iris

gplot <- function(prd){
  ggplot(summed_iris) +
    geom_col(aes_(x = ~Species,
                  y = ~Sepal.Length))+
    geom_errorbar(aes_(x = ~Species,
                       ymin = ~Sepal.Length -prd,
                       ymax = ~Sepal.Length + prd))

}

gplot(0.5)
```

[image]

EDIT: to the question in the comment:

In the case when `prd` is the column name of the data perhaps it is best to precompute the values:

```
gplot <- function(prd){
  ymin <-  with(summed_iris, get("Sepal.Length") - get(prd))
  ymax <-  with(summed_iris, get("Sepal.Length") + get(prd))
  summed_iris <- data.frame(summed_iris, ymin, ymax)
  ggplot(summed_iris) +
    geom_col(aes_(x = ~Species,
                  y = ~Sepal.Length))+
    geom_errorbar(aes_(x = ~Species,
                       ymin = ~ymin,
                       ymax = ~ymax))

}
gplot("Petal.Length")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the upcoming ggplot2 2.3.0 (to be released in late June 2018), `aes_(...)` is soft-deprecated and the recommendation is to use tidy eval. This means in the context here that you write `!!prd` when you want the content of the variable `prd` instead of the symbol `prd`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_all(~mean(.)) -> summed_iris

gplot <- function(prd){
  ggplot(summed_iris) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_errorbar(
      aes(x = Species, ymin = Sepal.Length - !!prd, ymax = Sepal.Length + !!prd)
    )
}

gplot(0.5)
```

[image]

And if you want the function `gplot()` to be able to take symbols just like `aes()` does, then you need to add an `enquo()` at the beginning of the function definition. It captures the expression that was provided to the function as well as the enclosing environment.

```r
gplot <- function(prd){
  prd <- enquo(prd)
  ggplot(summed_iris) +
    geom_col(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_errorbar(
      aes(x = Species, ymin = Sepal.Length - !!prd, ymax = Sepal.Length + !!prd)
    )
}

gplot(Petal.Length)
```

[image]

```r
scale <- 1/5
gplot(scale*Petal.Length)
```

[image]