# Plot y = mx + c with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basic question, ggplot doesn't seem to be doing what I expect though.

```
ggplot(data=data.frame( x=c(-1,2),y=c(-1,2) ), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_blank() + 
  geom_abline(slope = -1 , intercept = 1)
```

I'm expecting this to plot :

[image]

It's plotting :

[image]

Comment: Then you may need to clarify "the correct result". Intercept in a linear regression is commonly defined as the value of y when x is zero. Your abline clearly runs through (x = 0, y = 1). The limits of the plot area is given by the range of your data.

Comment: Also please read the help text `?geom_abline`: "If you use arguments, e.g. `geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)`, then behind the scenes the geom makes a new data frame containing just _the data you've supplied_"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plot `ggplot2` draws is not incorrect. It draws the function over the scales necessary to represent the data you pass to the `aes` call. It doesn't care whether you actually draw the data in a `geom` or not.

To illustrate the issue, it is helpful to add the actual data points to a plot and make the x- and y-axis more visible. The code below

```
ggplot(data=data.frame( x=c(-1,2),y=c(-1,2) ), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = -1, col = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

gives you:
[image]

Since you only want to plot a subsection of the above plot, just correct the scales (and don't draw the axes and datapoints). Then you get the result you desire:

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=c(-1,2), y=c(-1,2)), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_blank() +  # not necessary, taken from the OP's question
  geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = -1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: @baxx Do you happen to remember this post: [How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots) ;)

Comment: the problem was basic interpretation, as markus seems to have made a similar error. I feel that having something basic like this that directly answers how to plot y=mx + c might be useful to others in future though. In this case, plotting the axis with geom_hline() and geom_vline() would have been enough to demonstrate that the graph was in fact correct, and that I am in fact too tired.

Comment: @apitsch perhaps you could consider adding the case of there being axis lines to more clearly demonstrate the problem. Here's a link to a plot you could use : https://i.imgur.com/kh4FLaw.png , here's a link to the code : http://vpaste.net/IVLln

Comment: I learned something about setting the limits in `ggplot2` but wouldn't it have been easier to just `ggplot()+
  geom_abline(intercept = 1, slope = -1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))` instead of going through `geom_blank` in the first place.  Is there some subtility i am missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think ggplot2 does exactly what you ask it to do: you draw an empty canvans with goes from (-1, -1) to (2, 2) and then you add a abline. If you want to match the canvans to your exampe, just adjust the coordinates of the points that you specify:

```
library(tidyverse) 
ggplot(data=data.frame( x=c(0,2),y=c(1,0)), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    geom_blank() + 
    geom_abline(slope = -1 , intercept = 1)
```