# ggplot confidence interval not filling the whole dataset for my linear mixed model

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

my ggplot R-code works perfectly ok with my other datasets but I'm stumbled with why it's not working for one particular data set. See image below where the filled confidence interval stops at 0.10:
[image]

For reproducing the problem:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)
SurfaceCoverage <- c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12)
SpecificSurfaceEnergy <- c(18.0052997,15.9636971,14.2951057,13.0263081,13.0816591,13.3825573,2.9267577,2.2889628,1.8909175,1.0083036,0.5683574,0.1681063)
sample <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

highW <- data.frame(sample,SurfaceCoverage,SpecificSurfaceEnergy)

highW$sample <- sub("^", "Wettable", highW$sample)
highW$RelativeHumidity <- "High relative humidity"; highW$group <- "Wettable"
highW$sR <- paste(highW$sample,highW$RelativeHumidity)

dfhighW <- data.frame(
  "y"=c(highW$SpecificSurfaceEnergy),
  "x"=c(highW$SurfaceCoverage),
  "b"=c(highW$sample),
  "sR"=c(highW$sR)
)

mixed.lme <- lme(y~log(x),random=~1|b,data=dfhighW)
pred.mmhighW <- ggpredict(mixed.lme, terms = c("x"))

(ggplot(pred.mmhighW) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = predicted)) +          # slope
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = predicted - std.error, ymax = predicted + std.error), 
                fill = "lightgrey", alpha = 0.5) +  # error band
    geom_point(data = dfhighW,                      # adding the raw data (scaled values)
               aes(x = x, y = y, shape = b)) + 
    xlim(0.01,0.2) + 
    ylim(0,30) +
    labs(title = "") + 
    ylab(bquote('Specific Surface Energy ' (mJ/m^2))) +
    xlab(bquote('Surface Coverage ' (n/n[m]) )) +
    theme_minimal()
)
```

Can someone advise me how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The last part of your ribbon has disappeared because you have excluded it from the plot. The lower edge of your ribbon is the following vector:

```r
pred.mmhighW$predicted - pred.mmhighW$std.error
#> [1]  3.91264018  2.37386628  1.47061258  0.82834206  0.32935718 -0.07886245
```

Note the final value is a small negative number, but you have set the y axis limits with:

```r
ylim(0, 30)
```

So anything negative will be cut off. If you change to

```r
ylim(-2, 30)
```

You get

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron!!!!! Omg I keep making such simple mistakes. You save my day. Also I probably need to rest to have a fresh eye to pick this up. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is already answered previously, but `coord_cartesian` and `scales::squish` are two solutions to this problem.

- `coord_cartesian` adjusts the viewport *without* adjusting the spacing of grid lines etc. (unlike `xlim()`/`scale_*_continuous(limits = ...)`, which will "zoom")
- `scales::squish()` is suboptimal if you are "squishing" lines and points, not just edgeless polygons (in the case of fill/polygons, squishing and clipping produce the same results)

```r
gg0 <- (ggplot(pred.mmhighW) 
    + geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = predicted - std.error,
                      ymax = predicted + std.error), 
                  fill = "lightgrey", alpha = 0.5)
    + theme_minimal()
)

## set lower limit to 5 for a more obvious effect
gg0 + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(5, 30))
gg0 + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5, 30),
                         ## oob = "out of bounds" behaviour
                         oob = scales::squish)
```

Comment: this is almost the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000066/clip-only-1-axis-using-coord-cartesian/57002219#57002219