# How to change the Y range for ggplot (geom_col) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I am trying to create 2 ggplot bar graphs for text analysis to compare frequencies as percentages from the dictionary "loughran". Here is my code for one of the graphs. How can I edit my y range so that both graphs start at 0% and end at 100%? This way, it would be much easier to see the differences.

```
ggplot(loughran_nc) +
  aes(x = fct_reorder(sentiment, perc), y = perc)+
  geom_col()+
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("Sentiment")+
  ggtitle("Sentiment Analysis: Non-Complaints Loughran dictionary")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Edit your post to include `dput(loughran_nc)` or if the data is too big `dput(head(loughran_nc, 20))` to share first 20 rows.

Comment: `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,100))` if 100% is coded as 100, otherwise use `c(0,1)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)

Answer (score 0):

you can set limits within `coord_cartesian()`

Some quick data:

```
library(tidyverse)
loughran_nc <- data.frame(sentiment = c("words","for","some","data"),perc=c(40,60,20,80))
```

Then your plot + 1 line:

```
ggplot(loughran_nc) +
  aes(x = fct_reorder(sentiment, perc), y = perc)+
  geom_col()+
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("Sentiment")+
  ggtitle("Sentiment Analysis: Non-Complaints Loughran dictionary")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `coord_cartesian()` is to use `scale_y_continuous()` or `ylim()`.

- `scale_y_continuous()` lets you specify all sorts of attributes to the y axis; limits, breaks, name etc (see `?scale_y_continuous`). For your example, you can add `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100))` to your code
- `ylim()` is simple, and adding `ylim(c(0, 100))` would also do the same job