# ggplot with 2 y axes and different scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, multiple-axes

I want to make a ggplot with 2 y-axes and control both y axes scales.
I found this:

[ggplot with 2 y axes on each side and different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales)

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    "mpg (US)", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1.20, name = "mpg (UK)")
  )
```

[image]

I would like to control the left y-axes to limits between -20 and 110 (just an example)

Comment: Doesn't setting `limits = c(-20, 110)` do the trick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots

Comment: it worked:


```ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
 
  scale_y_continuous(
    "mpg (US)", limits=c(-10,200),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1.20, name = "mpg (UK)")
    
  )
```