# How to show a boxplot with limited Y-axis without actually limiting the results?

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I want to create a number of boxplots in 1 graphic to compare the different boxplots. The code I've written works, but the results differ so much that the graphic is basically useless. Because there are so many outliers, you can't see the actual boxplot. I want to limit the y-axis so that it only shows results up to a certain point, but this also actually limits the results, which I don't want! In other words, I want the y-axis to only show results up to y=70, but I want the results of 70 or above to still be calculated into the results. When I use the ylim function, this does not actually include the results that aren't in the limit. **So, how do I limit my graphic, but only graphically and not the actual results?**

I'm using ggplot. This is the code, although I doubt it is helpful since there the question is theoretical.

```
ggplot(dataorgrec,aes(x=Soortnieuw,y=AantalGRFBYE,fill=GRFBYE))+ 
  geom_boxplot()+
  ggtitle("Aantal recensies van categorieën van organisaties \n (beperkt tot 70 recensies per organisatie)")+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ylab("Aantal recensies")+xlab("")+ylim(0,100)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1D8DB0","#8EA9DB","#DCE7F0"),name="",labels=c("Google Review","Facebook","Yelp"))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10))
```

Comment: Set the limits via `coord_cartesian(ylim = ...)` instead of via `ylim()`. Doing so will "zoom" on the desired range. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

Set the limits via `coord_cartesian(ylim = ...)` instead of via `ylim()`. Doing so will "zoom" on the desired range. See e.g. [How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)